# Custom report from SQL query

Tags: magento2, sql, custom-reports

I want to get `order total` of the month `January 2019` for complete orders

I need to know `tables related to this query`, or if someone can share query that would be great.

Comment: order total, you mean the total number of orders for year 2019 or the total sum of amount of all the order for the specific month?

Comment: I need sum amount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions seems double meaning for me, so here I'll post my answer assuming:

**You want to get the Total Numbers of order for the specific month, below query should work**

```
SELECT count(entity_id) FROM sales_order where state='complete' and status='complete' and month(created_at) = '01' and year(created_at) = '2019';
```

**You want to get the total sum amount you can try this (This will filter only order that are completed):**

```
SELECT sum(base_grand_total) FROM sales_order where state='complete' and status='complete' and month(created_at) = '01' and year(created_at) = '2019';
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is query which will give you order total of completed order's for month jan 2019:

```
SELECT sum(base_grand_total) FROM  sales_order
WHERE created_at >='2018-12-31 23:59:59.000' AND created_at <= '2019-02-31 
23:59:59.000' AND status='complete'
```

Comment: Thanks Mohit, but it is showing warning that incorrect datetime format

Comment: Thanks for answer. +1